# Cross apply in MY SQL

Tags: mysql, cross-apply

Am trying to convert this Sql server script to mysql.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA A
CROSS APPLY 
(
SELECT TOP 1 UID
FROM TableB 
WHERE BetID = A.BetID
AND BETCODE = A.BETCODE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN InfoCode > '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,UID
)Z
WHERE Z.UID = A.UID
```

Can please advise as how, I know I can change CROSS JOIN and Limit 1 but still it fails

Answer (score 0):

in you can't use TOP but use limit so you could try  and in MySql the scope for subquery table is differente respect to SQL_SERVER so you must buil the join inside the subquery

```
  SELECT A.*
  FROM TableA A
  CROSS JOIN  
  ( SELECT UID
    FROM TableB 
    INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON  BetID = A.BetID
      AND BETCODE = A.BETCODE
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN InfoCode > '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,UID
      LIMIT 1
       ) Z 
    WHERE  Z.UID = A.UID
```

or  a cross join with a single result could be also translate as an inner join

```
  SELECT A.*
  FROM TableA A
  INNER JOIN  
  ( SELECT UID
    FROM TableB 
   INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON  BetID = A.BetID
      AND BETCODE = A.BETCODE
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN InfoCode > '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,UID
      LIMIT 1
       ) Z ON   Z.UID = A.UID
```

Comment: I tried both, both give me error like Unknown column  'A.BetID'  in 'where clause'

Comment: answer  updated .. added  the inner join in subquery for scope  issue ..